# jenkins shared library declare custom step with optional arguments and closure

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I am creating a custom step using a global shared library (vars/mystep.groovy). The step takes 3 optional, named arguments and a required closure. This is pretty standard for a jenkins step, many built-in steps have this pattern.

```
mystep arg3: "foo", arg1: [ 1, 2, 3] {
    // somecode here
}
```

OR

```
mystep {
    // somecode here
}
```

My problem is the declaration of the call() function. Either it is not matching the signature of the actual call, resulting in `org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method` errors, which means that whatever signatures the call() function is defining are not matching the caller. Or I get null values for the arguments.

I've tried several things, none of which quite work. The obvious ones were:

- `def call(arg1=null, arg2=null, arg3=null, Closure somecode)`
- `def call(Map args, Closure somecode)`
- `def call(Map args = [:], Closure somecode = null)`
- `def call(args)`

In some cases I can get it to work with parameters, but then it fails if no arguments and just the closure are used. Or the other way around. But so far I haven't found the magic formula that works in all cases.

How should I define the call method so that it matches the step usage?

Answer (score 0):

After many iterations I found a working formula. It's not perfect. Requires two modifications:

#1: have to use () when calling the step. Not sure why, it's just syntactic sugar according to groovy.

```
mystep () {
   // somecode
}
```

OR

```
mystep (arg3:"foo", arg1: [1,2,3]) {
    // somecode
}
```

Without the () various errors pop out.

#2 overload the call() function in the mystep.goovy file.

```
def call(Closure somecode) {
    mystep(arg1: null, arg2: null, arg3: null, somecode)
}

def call(Map args, Closure somecode=null) {
    def arg1 = args.get('arg1', null)
    ...
```

This does not do any type checking or handle unknown or invalid arguments, so I'm open to a better solution if there is one.